# Fiz uma aplicativo socket cliente/servidor mas só funciona pelo emulador

Tags: java, android, socket

Fiz uma aplicativo socket cliente/servidor, onde o cliente é um aparelho com android e o servidor é feito em java. A principio esta tudo ok, no emulador ele roda corretamente, mas quando instalo o apk no celular ele não funciona, ele diz que o aplicativo parou.

Comment: Pode ser a configuração da sua rede. O emulador está rodando no mesmo PC (eu imagino) e em `localhost`, ou seja, tem menos barreiras entre eles. Já no aparelho até as configurações do seu roteador podem interferir.

Comment: Se der, mostre as partes do código referentes ao servidor e ao cliente.

Comment: Seu Android Manifest está pedindo as liberações de Internet e 3G?

Answer (score 1):

Verifique o Firewall não esta bloqueando acesso externo de seu PC. 
Quando for realizar a conexão utilize [AsyncTask](http://mobilidade.fm/tutoriais/tutorial-dev/2011/06/conhecendo-asynctask/) pois se a conexão demorar vai dar timeout na aplicação

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma versão do apk que possua o ip do computador e não "localhost" na sua mesma faixa de ip. Dessa forma vc terá que instalar o app no seu Smartphone e terá que se conectar na mesma rede do seu computador, onde está localizado o seu servidor.